# Transforming runnable() from Java to Android

Tags: android

I did a chatting application based on Java. Updating the chat window is based on this method:

```
//change/update chatWindow
private void showMessage(final String m){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
        new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                chatWindow.append("/n" + m);
            }
        }   
    );
}
```

How can I implement this method on Android? `SwingUtilities` is not available.

Comment: What did you find missing in the documentation? http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html

Answer (score 3):

Use either Handler (android.os.Handler):
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

or any [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) by using [`post`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [`postDelayed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) methods

or the [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) method [`runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) while calling from any other Thread.